# Compile PIC assembly with NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, pic

I'm looking to compile asm file on netbook with Ubuntu 12.04 and NASM.
i try to use the following command to get a hex: `nasm -f elf myFile.asm`.
The asm file is for a PIC16F628A.

Here the content of myFile.asm :

http://pastebin.com/Rmaqhuv0

and there, a part of errors i got...

```
zeroKey.asm:6: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:7: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
zeroKey.asm:8: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:14: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:15: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:16: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:16: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:17: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:17: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:18: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:18: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:19: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:19: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:20: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:20: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:21: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:21: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:22: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:22: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:23: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:23: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:24: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:24: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:25: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:25: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:26: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:26: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:27: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:27: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:28: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:28: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:29: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:29: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:30: error: symbol `DE' redefined
zeroKey.asm:30: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:69: error: symbol `Org' redefined
zeroKey.asm:69: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:72: error: parser: instruction expected
zeroKey.asm:77: error: symbol `GOTO' redefined
...
```

Someone can explain me how can i compile and why there is an error?

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10.07/html/nasmdoc1.html#section-1.1) of the tools you want to use. You're using the wrong assembler. NASM is an x86 assembler. It does not understand PIC assembly.

> The Netwide Assembler, NASM, is an 80x86 and x86-64 assembler

Maybe if you explain what you want to do with that file we can suggest better solutions to your problem.

Comment: Well i m not asm fluent developer cause i used to develop with language like Java/PHP/Javascript so i m lost with that domain but i ll try to explain.
In fact this asm is used to program a security chip for arcade machine. It is used to check if the game is alright. The arcade system is named "Naomi" and it is used with netdimm to boot on a GD rom.
There is a 16f628a on netdimm the PIC i would like to program is this PIC.
So!
I would like to compile asm to get a .hex file and then be able to program the PIC.
Put that PIC on netdimm of my Naomi and play :)

Comment: Then you need an assembler for that PIC ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an assembler (or compiler) designed for your chip.  [This site](http://www.winpicprog.co.uk/index.htm) appears to have links to software used to assemble and possibly debug the chip in question.  With a little google work, you should be able to find the rest of what you need.  The chip itself seems pretty straight forward to use.

Comment: Ok i ll try it tonight :)